# Performance vs readability in Spark -- Intermediate calculations

Tags: apache-spark

The open bounty about performance vs readability made me wonder: Is there any difference between:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...
val final = df.filter(...).select(...)
```

and:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...
val filtered = df.filter(...)
val final = filtered.select(...)
```

in terms of performance? Same goes for `RDD` -- if I do `RDD.filter` and assign the result to a `val` and then do `RDD.map`, does that middle assignment have a cost?

I'm not sure why, but I have this vague belief that these would cause unnecessary overhead.

Urban myth or confirmed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only overhead I can come up with is creating a `val` that points to an `RDD` on the driver. Not sure how many ms that takes Scala ;-)

First of all in your example nothing would happen as you are not making Spark submit any **jobs**. A job is only submitted on actions (i.e. `collect()` etc.). The assignment you showed just declares an RDD but doesn't trigger any actions.

Because of the above all RDDs can be **lazy** so you don't need to compute anything.

When you submit a **job** Spark will create a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of the **tasks** (filter, map, reduce, groupByKey etc.) which have to be performed to get the job done :-) There are two types of tasks: **narrow** and **wide**. Wide tasks require a data shuffle. If any shuffle is required Spark will divide your tasks into **stages**, i.e. first stage would have all tasks before the shuffle, second stage would have all tasks after the shuffle.

Thanks to this Spark, before running anything, can actually squash invocations like the one you posted above into a single stage that would run on the same partition (the whole filter -> select chain).

```
val df: DataFrame = ...
val filtered = df.filter(...)
val final = filtered.select(...)
final.collect()
```

Spark will create, internally, a **lineage** for the `final` RDD and figure out that the `filter()` and `select()` can be parallelized (well it will also check for caches) and run together on the same partition. The **lineage** in both cases should be the same for that `collect()`.

There are some cool talks about Spark internals, for instance [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmL0N3qfSc8) or [this one from Spark Summit 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HG2Yd-3r4-M).