# Structuring multiple transformations into a single step

Tags: apache-spark

An RDD needs to be transformed, and there are several steps in the transformation.

One option is to put all the steps into one function:

```
rdd.map {x => 
  x.field1 = // some logic
  x.field2 = // some logic
  x.field3 = // some logic

  x
}
```

The issues with the above are:

- each of the aforementioned logic steps could be quite large, so
  structuring the code is more challenging.
- some steps may potentially be dependent on transformations to the RDD in previous steps.

An alternative is as follows:

```
val transformedRdd = rdd.map(function1).map(function2).map(function3)
```

This both solves the previous issues. However, is it efficient? Is it any different to:

```
val rdd1 = rdd.map(function1)
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(function2)
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(function)
```

Thanks

Comment: I asked your last question before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932388/performance-vs-readability-in-spark-intermediate-calculations  Enjoy.